# arrays and static methods java

Tags: java, arrays, static-methods

I have a question on how to call an array static method. In my case, I believe that my array static method is fine because the compiler does not complain about it, but it does when I call it, it says `double cannot be converted to double[]` How can I fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
// create allowed x values for calculation static method
public static double[] allowedValuesX(double[] x, double[] y, int choice){
    double allowedVx[] = new double[choice];
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < allowedVx.length; i++){
        if((Math.pow(x[i], 2) + (Math.pow(y[i], 2))) <= 1){
            allowedVx[i] = x[i];
        }
    }
    return allowedVx;
}
// main method
public static void main(String args[]){
// create Scanner object
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // call to promptUser
    promptUser();

    // create variable for recieving user input
    int choice = in.nextInt();

    double x[] = new double[choice];
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        x[i] = Math.random();
    }
// call to allowed x values
    allowedValuesX(x[i], y[j], choice);
```

Comment: `allowedValuesX(x[i], y[j], choice);` vs `double[] x, double[] y, int choice`. Do you see the difference? Your signature expects an array but you're calling it with a single value from the array (aka: a single `double`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing specific array elements when calling `allowedValuesX`:

```
allowedValuesX(x[i], y[j], choice);
```

But you should pass the arrays themselves, to match the parameter types of the method:

```
allowedValuesX(x, y, choice);
```